# How to install elsarticle.cls for Lyx in Ubuntu

Tags: lyx, ubuntu, elsarticle

How can I use the [Elsevier article class](https://ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle) in Lyx?

I have already installed `sudo apt install texlive-publishers`, `sudo apt install texlive-science` and `sudo apt install texlive` packages. Still I see the Elsevier article class unavailable:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found that after installing those packages I had to got Lyx → Tools → Reconfigure. Now the Elsevier article class is available.